# Modelagem do banco de dados PostgreSQL/VisualStudio

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-studio

Olá.

Tenho este formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto a modelagem do banco ali na parte de "produtos" pretendo carregar todos produtos(nome, quantidade disponível, valor unitário) e quando a pessoa selecionar algum e colocar a quantidade irá fazer o cálculo do total.

Minha dúvida é: A pessoa vai selecionar 5 produtos e gravar, como preciso modelar no banco de dados?

Porque a pessoa poderá pesquisar pelo ID e deverá trazer já com os produtos que foram selecionados.

As tabelas/formulários que tenho no banco são esses:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
    cod_cliente SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nomeCliente VARCHAR(100),
    tipoPessoa INT,
    CNPJ INT,
    CPF INT,
    inscricaoEstadual INT,
    inscricaoMunicipal INT,
    CEP INT,
    endereco VARCHAR(100),
    numero VARCHAR(5),
    bairro VARCHAR(50),
    complemento VARCHAR(50),
    cidade VARCHAR(50),
    foneComercial INT,
    email VARCHAR(40),
    contato VARCHAR(20),
    celular INT,
    observacoes VARCHAR(240)
);

CREATE TABLE FORNECEDORES(
    cod_fornecedor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nomeFornecedor VARCHAR(100),
    tipoPessoa INT,
    CNPJ INT,
    CPF INT,
    razaoSocial VARCHAR(200),
    inscricaoEstadual INT,
    inscricaoMunicipal INT,
    CEP INT,
    endereco VARCHAR(100),
    numero VARCHAR(5),
    bairro VARCHAR(50),
    complemento VARCHAR(50),
    cidade VARCHAR(50),
    foneComercial INT,
    email VARCHAR(40),
    contato VARCHAR(20),
    celular INT,
    observacoes VARCHAR(240) 
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUTOS(
    cod_produto SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nomeProduto VARCHAR(100),
    codigoProduto VARCHAR(20),
    valorVenda REAL,
    valorCusto REAL,
    disponivelEstoque INT,
    minimoEstoque INT,
    maximoEstoque INT,
    unidadeMedida INT,
    pesoLiquido REAL,
    pesoBruto REAL,
    cod_fornecedor INT REFERENCES FORNECEDORES(cod_fornecedor)
);

CREATE TABLE SERVICOS(
    cod_servico SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nomeServico VARCHAR(100),
    tempoExecucao TIME,
    custoServico REAL
);

CREATE TABLE ORDEMSERVICO(
    cod_os SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    status INT,
    formaPagamento INT,
    responsavel INT,
    dataAbertura DATE,
    dataInicio DATE,
    dataPrevisao DATE,
    descricao VARCHAR(240),
    valorProdutosTotal REAL,
    acrDes INT,
    percentual REAL,
    valorTotalOS REAL,
    observacoes VARCHAR(240),

    cod_cliente INT REFERENCES CLIENTE(cod_cliente),
    cod_produto INT REFERENCES PRODUTO(cod_produto)

    /** incompleto **/
);
```

Comment: já resolveu essa questão  ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis não resolvi cara, eu não consigo entender como faço para armazenar vários produtos que eu selecionar no dataGrid, se puder me mostrar um exemplo ou indicar algo que eu possa ler sobre..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de uma tabela de vendas/os e uma tabela dos itens dessa venda...
relação simples de cardinalidade 1:N onde uma venda pode ter vários itens, e um item pode estar em somente uma venda.

Tabela de venda:

```
id*|data|cliente|status|formapagamento|...|etc
```

Tabela de itens:

```
item*|venda*fk|produto fk|quantidade|valor|...|etc
```

as colunas com * são chave primária, com fk, chave estrangeira.

Repare que na tabela de itens, a chave primária é composta utilizando o id da venda (que também é estrangeira) junto a um sequencial (item).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Me deu uma luz, irei testar com base no que me disse.. depois atualizo aqui